# How to cancel activity after message boundary event

Tags: workflow, activiti, bpmn

Having the following process

[image]

and a message boundary event which has `cancelActivity` set to `false` so that after `Should cancel` the `Sub Process` could continue where it was before the event was received - in case that `No` was selected.

How could I simulate as if `cancelActivity` was set to `true` in case that the user selects `Yes` (i.e. cancel/stop `Sub Process` when the `No` end is reached)?

Please ask if I wasn't clear about this.

Comment: Can you describe what you actually want to achieve? Who sends that message you model here with a boundary message event? Is that already a "cancellation message" or do you really want to decide after having received that message whether you actually want to cancel or not?

Comment: Hi, explained at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the boundary event attached to the sub process, there is no way of going to `another task` after `should cancel`.
You can neither use link events (not allowed from parent to sub process), nor a simple sequence flow (not allowed between two processes).

So I guess you need attach the message event to each relevant task **within** the sub process or you need to use two separate boundary events (one interrupting and one non-interrupting).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I don't need to go to another task, I just need to leave the SubProcess active on "Should Not Cancel", which works ok if cancelActive is false, and terminate the whole process along with Subprocess on the "Yes" end, which I now figured works if I use Terminate End Event instead. I'm accepting your answer though as it's probably right in context of my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Further the answer above.
The process flow really doesnt properly capture your requirement.
You should have the email event running in parallel to your sub process.
On receipt of the email, flow directly into the should cancel human/user task.
If yes, send a signal event (signals are easier to implement than messages) that is captured by a signal boundary event receiver on the sub process and simply flow to the end (i.e. terminate).

If no, you simply exit (you may need to start another email receiver - depends on your requirements).

This way, the sub process boundary event is not triggered until after you have made your decision to terminate or not.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need the bpmn definition below

[image: should task]